# Windows Color Scheme (Theme) Program

Tags: windows, software-rec, color-theme

I’m wondering if there is a program that will let a user select one or two colors and create a color-scheme (ie, Windows theme) based on it/them so that the user does not have to manually set each and every color.

Comment: I’m still looking for a program (especially one that has built-in support for Windows color schemes), but I found the [ColorHexa](http://www.colorhexa.com/) site which provides a pile of analysis and information for any given color, including different kinds of color themes that include it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Google I found [WindowBlinds](http://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/). And there's a download [here](http://download.cnet.com/WindowBlinds/3000-2072_4-10026826.html?tag=pwd;listScroller).

Comment: I’m quite familiar with WindowBlinds and it is not what I am looking for. Besides being costly, its purpose is for themes and skins, not color schemes (though themes can include colors, WB doesn’t specifically do what I asked about).